# Why does psql throw ERROR: character with byte sequence 0xd0 0x9e in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

SQL shell(PostgreSQL) often throw this error, e.g. when I forget to close brackets or when I try to drop table `DROP TABLE book;`. I do not know why.

`ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xd0 0x9e in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"`

I have already seen similar questions. But switch client encoding kind of: `\encoding UTF8`  do not help... After, I have error, like:
`` DzD"D~D`DsD?:  D_Ñ^D,D±DºD° Ñ?D,D½Ñ,D°DºÑ?D,Ñ?D° (D¿Ñ?D,D¼DµÑ?D½D_Dµ D¿D_D»D_D¶DµD½D,Dµ: ")") LINE 1: ); ^ ``

Comment: your table doesn't have utf8. First check the table which encoding you ave, te chekc th connction string that must ave te sa,e encoding as has the table/column.

Comment: The byte sequence 0xD0 0x9E in UTF-8 would represent U+041E "CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER O", in case that gives any clues. It would indeed by unrepresentable in Windows-1252, which doesn't have any Cyrillic letters.

Answer (score 0):

The strings that can't be displayed properly are error messages translated into the language configured with `lc_messages`.
In your case it's a language with Cyrillic characters, for instance it could be Russian (see the result of `show lc_messages;` in SQL).
If the client side has an incompatible character set, such as `win1252` which is meant for Western European characters, it can't display the Cyrillic characters.

To illustrate the problem, first let's display when it's properly configured on both sides.

```
postgres=# \encoding ISO_8859_5
postgres=# set lc_messages to 'ru_RU.iso88595';
SET
postgres=# drop table does_not_exist;
ОШИБКА:  таблица "does_not_exist" не существует
```

Now let's switch to a `win1252` encoding:

```
postgres=# \encoding WIN1252
postgres=# drop table does_not_exist;
ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xd0 0x9e in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"
```

You get the same error as in the question, because the russian error text when attempting to drop a non-existing table contains `U+041E "CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER O"`, a character that doesn't exist in WIN1252.

The solution is to use a client-side configuration that is compatible with Cyrillic, such as `UTF-8` (recommended as it supports all languages) or the mono-byte encodings [`win1251`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) or [`iso-8859-5`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-5).
Alternatively, some installations prefer to configure the server to output untranslated error messages (set `lc_messages` to `C` for instance).

Be aware that both your **terminal configuration** and the psql **`client_encoding`** must be set together and be compatible. If you do `\encoding UTF-8` but your terminal is still configured for a mono-byte encoding like `win1252` you'll get the kind of garbled output that you mention in the last part of question.

Example for a **wrong mix** of terminal set to `iso-8859-1` (western european), a psql client-side encoding forced to UTF8, and messages with  Cyrillic characters:

```
postgres=# \encoding
UTF8

postgres=# show lc_messages ;
  lc_messages   
----------------
 ru_RU.iso88595

postgres=# drop table does_not_exist;
ÐÐÐ°Ð±Ð»ÐžÑÐ° "does_not_exist" ÐœÐµ ÑÑÑ ÐµÑÑÐ²ÑÐµÑ
```